# How to make calls and visit website from context menu on long clicking listview items?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, contextmenu, onlongclicklistener

I am trying to learn the Android onLongclick context menu actions. When clicking an item on list it displays two action image one for calling and another for website url. But I am having null pointer exception. When toasting using the  toast method it can display number and url. But this is not what i want to to. Its just for test. I want to dial the number when phone action is clicked and visit website when url action is clicked. I have commented toast for doing so. And tried to create perform call and performUrl() methods. I took idea from the example with toast so i tried to modify it but its simply not working so i commented the performCall() and performUrl() methods for now. Could anyone suggest how to make these things happen?

I have a department class which is a pure java class.

```
public class DepartmentActivity extends Activity {
    //Department dept = new Department();
    private ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<Department> adapter;
    //String list_item;
    Object mActionMode;
    private Department[] myDepartment = {
            new Department("CS", "cs@yahoo.edu", "405.111.2222"),
            new Department("Biology", "bio@yahoo.edu", "405.222.3333"),
            new Department("Business", "business@yahoo.com", "405.333.4444"),
            new Department("Music", "music@yahoo.com", "405.444.5555"),
            new Department("Engineering", "engg@ucoll.com", "405.555.6666"),
            new Department("Nursing", "nursing@yahoo.com", "213.555.6666")
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_department);

        listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.deptlist, deptList);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.deptlist, myDepartment);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        //listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        //listener = new listView.OnItemLongClickListener(this);


        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //list_item = myDepartment.toString();
                if (mActionMode != null){
                    return false;
                }
                mActionMode = DepartmentActivity.this.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                return true;

            }



        });


    }
    private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            //mode.setTitle(list_item);
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
            return true;
            //return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_phone:
                    performCall();
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_www:
                    //performUrl();
                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mActionMode = null;
        }
    };

    /*
    private void performCall() {

        SparseBooleanArray selected = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        String selectedNames ="";
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                int pos = selected.keyAt(i);
                selectedNames += " " + myDepartment[pos].getPhone();
            }


        }
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+selectedNames));
        startActivity(callIntent);

        //Toast.makeText(DepartmentActivity.this, "Call: " + selectedNames,
               // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    */

    /*
    private void performUrl() {
        SparseBooleanArray selected = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        String selectedNames = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
            if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                int pos = selected.keyAt(i);
                selectedNames += " " + myDepartment[pos].getUrl();
            }
        }

        //Toast.makeText(DepartmentActivity.this, "Url: " + selectedNames,
                //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    */
```

Stack trace

```
 ....PID: 3250
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.util.SparseBooleanArray.size()' on a null object reference
                      at esu.uco.rawal.p4rabina.DepartmentActivity.performCall(DepartmentActivity.java:108)
                      at esu.uco.rawal.p4rabina.DepartmentActivity.access$100(DepartmentActivity.java:18)
                      at esu.uco.rawal.p4rabina.DepartmentActivity$2.onActionItemClicked(DepartmentActivity.java:85)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onActionItemClicked(PhoneWindow.java:3540)
                      at com.android.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar$ActionModeImpl.onMenuItemSelected(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1093)
                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
                      at android.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:616)
                      at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:141)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace showing the exception?

Comment: @MobileDeveloper I have edited my question to include stake trace of errors.  I just uncommented performCall() method and called it in the switch part. Then i got this error.